# Fixing the location of a two column row with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So far I learned a bit about forms and collapsible panels in bootstrap and this is how far I got:

[image]

I don't know how to fix the issue that the label for "**Email**" and its Textbox are so far away from each other. That's the part I need help with. Is there a way I make them be in the center of this panel? or for example if they can start from where the header text of the panel ends?

Here is the HTML I have:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `form-inline` instead of having columns like that, your label will be next to your input. Add a `text-center` and it will center the them. E.g.:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-inline text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: oh  no ! It made the email label in center and went to next line and put the textbox with the width taking the whole screen.

Comment: I accidentally had `form-horizontal` instead of `form-inline`. I also nested another div in there.

Comment: Ok thanks, fixed that issue but now it is not boostrapy! meaning because it doesn't have columns, it doesn't resize the textbox at all when screen size is changed.

Comment: @Bohn, get even more Bootstrappy...try adding classes like `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4` to the form-inline div.